# How to show number of books published by each author each year

Tags: sql, join

I'm having trouble with this question: Show the number of books published each year by each author. Show only the rows for author who published more than 1 book in a year. The table should show author, Pubyear, and “Total Book Published in Year”. MediaID should not be used in this query, use MediaCode.

Tables:

Customer:
CustomerID
LastName
FirstName
Address
Suburb
City
PostalCode
Email
PhoneNumber
Gender
MemberStatus
MemberSince
Major

InventoryItem:
InventoryItemID
ItemID
Status
Condition

Item:
ItemID
Title
MediaID
Author
PubYear
Description
ReplacementCost
LostFee

Loan:
LoanID
CustomerID
InventoryItemID
CheckedOut
DueDate
CheckedIn
Renewals
OverdueFee

Media:
MediaID
MediaCode
MediaDescription
LoanPeriod
RenewalsAllowed
OverdueFee

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL join data from multiple tables with MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41090783/sql-join-data-from-multiple-tables-with-mysql)

Comment: What exactly is the trouble you're having? Show us what you've got so far and where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
select i.Author, i.PubYear, COUNT(m.MediaCode) as "Total Book Published in Year" 
from Item i
inner join Media m on i.MediaID = m.MediaID 
where COUNT(m.MediaCode) > 1 and i.PubYear = the_Year
group by i.Author, i.PubYear
```

Comment: Please add some context about why your code should resolve the problem.